# replace content in specific posts in wordpress true mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

hello i am new here and will be happy for the help 
i have 1000 posts in my site that contain the word "free" 
i need to replace the word "free" only in 20 posts that contain another word "blue" 
so from 1000 posts only 20 of them contain the word "blue" and in them i need to replace the word "free" 
anyone can help? how can i do it in one time true mysql
i know how to replace but not in specific posts.
i have tried to replace it using this query but it replace in all 1000 posts and its a problem for me this is what i have

UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, 'free', 'free3')

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a WHERE clause in your update statement.

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'free', 'free3' ) 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%blue%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'free', 'free3') 
WHERE LOCATE('blue', post_content) > 0
```